# Adding 'rolling numbers' for repeater control, Paging asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, repeater, paging

I am using repeater control and showing paging   '<< Previous      next >>'   it is working fine.

But i  want to show links (rolling numbers) in between like below:

Previous << 1 2 3 4 5   next >>

**have a look this picture for idea**.

[image]

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
      <table border="1" style="border-color: #336699;" cellspacing="0">              
         <tr style="background-color:#336699; color:White;">
            <td>Product ID</td>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
         </tr>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("ProductID") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("ProductName") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("UnitPrice") %></td>
         </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
      </table>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<div> <table width="500px" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td  width="25%"> <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"  /> 

     </td>

    <td  width="25%"><asp:HyperLink ID="linkPrev" runat="server">« Previous</asp:HyperLink> 


    </td>

     <td width="25%"><asp:HyperLink ID="linkNext" runat="server">Next »</asp:HyperLink></td>

     <td  width="25%"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  /> </td>


  </tr>
</table>    </div>
```

**c#**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {


                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Products", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
                Repeater1.DataBind();

                con.Close();

                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(table);

                PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
                pds.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
                pds.AllowPaging = true;

                pds.PageSize = 10;



                int currentPage;

                if (Request.QueryString["page"] != null)
                {
                    currentPage = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["page"]);




                }
                else
                {
                    currentPage = 1;
                }



                pds.CurrentPageIndex = currentPage - 1;


                Label1.Text = "Page " + currentPage + " of " + pds.PageCount;

                Label2.Text = "Results" + pds.DataSourceCount;



                if (!pds.IsFirstPage)
                {
                    linkPrev.NavigateUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?page=" + (currentPage - 1);
                }



               if (pds.IsFirstPage)
                {

                    linkPrev.Visible = false;


                    linkPrev.Style["display"] = "block";

                }




                if (!pds.IsLastPage)
                {
                    linkNext.NavigateUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?page=" + (currentPage + 1);
                }




                if (pds.IsLastPage)
                {


                    linkNext.Visible = false;
                    linkPrev.Style["display"] = "block";
                }


                Repeater1.DataSource = pds;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Google indexes only first page of these producs pages if you are not careful about type of buttons for 1 2 3 4 ..

Comment: simply i want to generate 1234 numbers as a links..

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `Repeater` and not just a `DataGrid`, where this behavior is built-in?

Comment: no reason just using.........is this not possible in repeater